# Why is my ondragstart operation being undone immediately after executing?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm making a drag-and-drop form builder with three levels of grouping: Sections, which contain Questions, which contain Options. Options can be dragged within and between Questions, and Questions can be dragged within and between Sections, and Sections can be ordered amongst each other.

I'm using Bootstrap's `collapse`/`show` classes to hide the majority of Questions as they begin being dragged, since some can have a dozen plus options, and leaving it open while dragging wouldn't let you see any questions beneath it.

However, as soon as the `ondragstart` executes and removes the `show` class from the body of the Question, collapsing it, it seems to be undone immediately.

I tried stepping through each and every line that gets called after `ondragstart` in the debugger, and couldn't find anything that would re-add the `show` Bootstrap class.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertgreenstreet/jrdmvasw/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I needed was to add a condition to the `ondragenter` function for Questions to check whether the item being dragged A) Had the `preventCollapse` class AND B) Was NOT also the item being dragged over:

```js
function addQuestionEventListeners(item) {
    /* Checking to see if the item being dragged is an option for a question so that
    the question won't collapse if it is */
    item.ondragstart = function(e) {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains('questionOption')) {
            fullForm.style.height = (fullForm.offsetHeight) + 'px';
            this.classList.add('dragging');
            this.querySelector('.collapse').classList.remove('show');
        };
    }
    item.ondragend = function(e) {
        this.classList.remove('dragging');
        this.querySelector('.collapse').classList.add('show');
        fullForm.style.height='';
    }
    item.ondragenter = function(e) {
        var dragging = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        if(dragging.classList.contains('preventCollapse') && dragging !== this) {
            this.querySelector('.collapse').classList.add('show');
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain like I'm five why an element would call its own `ondragenter` function? It doesn't make sense to me.